# How can I build a get request with url that contains parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angular-http

I am trying to do a get request to recover data from the server using the following url:

```
url = /api/projects/:projectId/scenarios
```

How can I do that using $http.get in AdngularJS?.

Comment: Hum... `$http.get(url)`? [The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), if needed.

Comment: I would like to build a get request something like this: $http.get('api/projects/:projectId/scenarios'), my question is wath happen with :projectId how can I pass this?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at Restangular, I like its notation more than standard angularjs $http or $resource.

```
Restangular.setBaseURL('/api/');
Restangular.one('projects', projectId).all('scenarios').getList().then(function(data) {
   myVariable = data;
});
```

[Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)